# Digitally sign a PDF using iTextSharp 4.1.6.0

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Is it possible to digitally sign a PDF using iTextSharp 4.1.6.0? If so, is there some example documentation in C#?

Comment: There is no example documentation for version 4.1.6 because that version is retired. However, you can find example documentation for versions 5.5.10 and 7.0.1 on http://developers.itextpdf.com

Comment: No. You could sign a PDF using that version in 2008, but signature standards have changed since that date. You should use a more recent version. Why on earth would you use a version of iTextSharp that has been declared End-of-Life such a long time ago. Your question doesn't make sense. It sounds as: can I watch TV in color on a black-and-white television set?

Comment: You might find some example code in the wild but it likely won't make you happy. On one hand it uses APIs which may nowadays be outdated and on the other hand they problem signatures not following current profiles.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to sign with that version. There was a description on how to sign - the internet archive is your [friend](https://web.archive.org/web/20130329022247/http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html).

And please note the comments of the iText folks that this is an outdated version - today there are newer standards like PAdES etc.

(I however disagree with Bruno's analogy: The question is not `"Can I watch color TV on my b&w television?"` BUT `"Can I still watch TV on a B&W television?"` Sure you can, in b&w. The question of why you'd stick with a b&w TV nowadays that's a different kettle of fish.)

Comment: We tried your suggestion and made further progress and added another question with next level of details in implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67073342/digitally-sign-a-pdf-using-itextsharp-4-1-6-0-without-keys-exportable-certificat